# Requests POST data not being appended to url

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to send a simple POST request to a server using requests.  I am doing (I think at least) exactly what the quickstart (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) is saying to do.  The POST request seems to be ignoring the data= tag and not appending the data to the end of the url.  This is what I have:

```
import requests, json

url = 'http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks'
payload = (('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2'))

r=requests.post(url, data=payload)
print 'url is: ', r.url
```

and the output is:

```
url is: http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

I don't know if it is relevant or not, but if I use the GET tag params=, the url is assembled as I expect:

```
r=requests.post(url, params=payload)

url is: http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/?key1=value&key1=value2
```

Anyone see anything wrong?  Thanks in advance

Comment: `data` in a `POST` is passed in the body, not in the URL. `params` is the correct argument for encoding it in the URL. Are you sure this a `POST` form?

Comment: See if this makes more sense: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to dump `payload` to `json` and use a `dict`

```
payload = {}

payload[key1] = value1
payload[key2] = value2

payload_data = json.dumps(payload)
r=requests.post(url, data=payload_data)
```

Comment: `data` is passed as the body of the message not in the URL. `requests` automatically converts a `dict` to `json`.

Comment: the url here would be `url = 'http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks`. I am not making `key-value pairs` in the `url`. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`POST` data is passed in the body of the request, not the URL. A `POST` HTTP request looks something like this

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Length: <length>

firstname=john&lastname=doe
```

So as you can see the URL does not get passed these parameters and this is important for a lot of reasons that I won't mention in this answer. However, if for some reason you do need to pass these parameter in the URL instead of the body of the request then here is oh you might do it.

```
import requests, urllib

url = 'http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks'
payload = (('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2'))

request_data = urllib.urlencode(payload) # Turns it into key1=value1&key1=value2

response = requests.post(url + "?" + request_data)
```

That will craft the request in the same way that you see it in the GET request that you have at the bottom of your answer, but instead as a POST request.